# Switch between file upload and text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to create a site which provides the option to the user to either add a website address (text) or upload a file.

I have provided a dropdown that gives them the option to select file or link.

Based on the selection, I want the next element(input element) to change to either to text box or file upload.

How do I achieve this?

Link Option -

[image: Link Option]

File Option -

[image: File Option]

Currently it is hardcoded.

Added a snippet.

```html
<div>
  <label>UpdateFileType</label>
  <select asp-for="UpdateFileType">
    <option>File</option>
    <option>Link</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label>UpdateFileLink</label>
  <input name="UpdateFileLink" class="files" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>UpdateFileLink</label>
  <input class="link" />
</div>
```

Comment: Share a snippet or any fiddle link.

Comment: try this : https://codepen.io/anupam-the-reactor/pen/NEbraw

Answer (score 1):

Use `id` and on change event show hide your `div` based on `id`.

```js
$("#div2").hide();
$("#ddchange").change(function() {
  var link = $(this).val();
  if (link == 'File') {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
  } else {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>UpdateFileType</label>
  <select asp-for="UpdateFileType" id="ddchange">
    <option>File</option>
    <option>Link</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="div1">
  <label>Update File Link</label>
  <input name="UpdateFileLink" class="files" type="file" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <label>Update Link</label>
  <input class="link" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
  <label>UpdateFileType</label>
   <select  onchange="toggleField()" id="ddlFileType">
        <option value="File">File</option>
        <option value="Link">Link</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div id="file" style="display:none">
  <label>UpdateFileLink</label>
  <input name="UpdateFileLink" class="files" type="file" />
</div>
<div id="link" style="display:none">
  <label>UpdateFileLink</label>
  <input class="link" />
</div>
<script>
function toggleField() {

var x = document.getElementById("ddlFileType");
switch (x.value) {
 case 'Link':
  document.getElementById("file").style = "display:none";
  document.getElementById("link").style = "display:block";
  break;
 case 'File':
  document.getElementById("link").style = "display:none";
  document.getElementById("file").style = "display:block";
  break;
}
}
</script>
```